# Spark incoming JSON stream processing

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I have been trying to complete a project in which I needed to send data stream using kafka to local Spark to process the incoming data. However I can not show and use the data frame in the right format. How can I resolve this issue?
Here is code for Kafka:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import json
from confluent_kafka import Producer

# Read CSV
df = pd.read_csv('timeseries.csv')
df = df.astype(str)

# Number of rows to send in each batch
batch_size = 100

# Kafka settings
kafka_bootstrap_servers = 'localhost:9092'
kafka_topic = 'T7'

# Create a Kafka producer
producer_config = {'bootstrap.servers': kafka_bootstrap_servers}
producer = Producer(producer_config)

# Total number of rows in the dataset
total_rows = len(df)

# Loop through the dataset and send 100 rows at a time
for i in range(0, total_rows, batch_size):
    batch = df.iloc[i:i + batch_size]

    # Select only the "id" and "value" columns
    selected_columns = batch[['id', 'date', 'value', 'label']]

    # Convert the selected columns to a JSON string
    json_data = selected_columns.to_json(orient='records')

    try:
        # Send the batch to the Kafka topic
        producer.produce(kafka_topic, key=str(batch['id'].iloc[0]), value=json_data.encode('utf-8'))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error sending batch: {e}")

    # Introduce a delay of 1 second between sending each batch
    time.sleep(1)

# Wait for any outstanding messages to be delivered and delivery reports received
producer.flush()
```

and this is the code that I use for Spark :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr, from_json, split, explode
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType

# Define your Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("SparkConsumeKafka") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.0") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Set log level to ERROR
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

# Read from the Kafka topic
df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "T8") \
    .load()

my_schema = (
    StructType()
    .add("id", StringType())
    .add("date", StringType())
    .add("value", StringType())
    .add("label", StringType())
)

# Deserialize the JSON data using the defined schema
df = df.select(
    explode(split(col("value").cast("string"), "\n")).alias("values"), 
    "timestamp"
)

df = df.select(
    from_json(col("values"), my_schema).alias("datas"), 
    "timestamp"
)

def show_batch(df, epoch_id):
    df = df.select(
        "datas.id",
        "datas.date",
        "datas.value",
        "datas.label",
        "timestamp"
    )

    df.show(truncate=False)
    

# Write to the console with formatted options
query = df.writeStream.foreachBatch(show_batch).start()

# Await termination
query.awaitTermination()

# Stop the Spark session
spark.stop()
```

This is the best i could get out of it
[image: spark data frame show]